# respond_with do not redirect to index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

I need help with the responder respond_with, 'cause when I create a new post (in this case) It doesn't redirect to the location specified. What can be?. This is the piece of my code that creates a new post but It's be redirected to create.html.erb and not the index.html.erb that I specified.

```
 def create
    @post = Post.create(params[:post])
    respond_with(@post, :status => :created, :location => posts_url)
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use "redirect_to" (from [ACIIcasts - Controllers in Rails 3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3)):

```
redirect_to @result, :notice => "Successfully converted original data."
```

If you are not confortable with the solution i found a workaround in a similar post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229079/302485)

```
def convert
  @result = Result.find(params[:id])
  @result.convert_original_data
  success = @result.save
  respond_with(@result) do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to result_path(@result) } if success
  end
end
```

Comment: It works, but the reason that I'm using respond_with is to avoid the specification of each format. So, Why the location attr doesn't work?. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to supply location.  It will do it automagically for you.

All you need to do is...

```
respond_with @post
```

It will set the correct status and redirect you to the posts_url.